# Iterative loop in dataframe - creating data dictionary dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have thousands of row in given block structure. In this structure First row - Response Comments, Second row- Customer name and Last row - Recommended are fixed. Rest of the fields/rows are not mandatory.

I am trying to write a code where I am reading Column Name = 'Response Comments' then Key = Column Values of next row (Customer Name).
This should be done from Row - Response Comments to Recommended,
Then breaking a loop and having new key value.

The data is from an Excel file:

```
from pandas import DataFrame 
import pandas as pd
import os 
import numpy as np 
xl = pd.ExcelFile('Filepath') 
df = xl.parse('Reviews_Structured') 
print(type (df))

RowNum        Column Name               Column Values                     Key

1       Response Comments   they have been unresponsive 
2       Customer Name       Brian   
             .
             .
             .
             .
13      Recommended         no
```

Any help regarding this loop code will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Mr. T for your reply and correcting me. This is my first my attempt in python coding. I am aware of data security, this is publicly available data, so no harm in sharing. However I am reading it from an excel file.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't see the exact post while editing it. I hope this will help now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to implement your logic is using `collections.defaultdict` and a nested dictionary structure. Below is an example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

# input data
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Response Comments', 'they have been unresponsive'],
                   [2, 'Customer Name', 'Brian'],
                   .....

                   [9, 'Recommended', 'yes']],
                  columns=['RowNum', 'Column Name', 'Column Values'])

# fill Key columns
df['Key'] = df['Column Values'].shift(-1)
df.loc[df['Column Name'] != 'Response Comments', 'Key'] = np.nan
df['Key'] = df['Key'].ffill()

# create defaultdict of dict
d = defaultdict(dict)

# iterate dataframe
for row in df.itertuples():
    d[row[4]].update({row[2]: row[3]})

# defaultdict(dict,
#             {'April': {'Customer Name': 'April',
#               'Recommended': 'yes',
#               'Response Comments': 'they have been responsive'},
#              'Brian': {'Customer Name': 'Brian',
#               'Recommended': 'no',
#               'Response Comments': 'they have been unresponsive'},
#              'John': {'Customer Name': 'John',
#               'Recommended': 'yes',
#               'Response Comments': 'they have been very responsive'}})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The only problem is - There are not only 3 rows Response comments, Customer Name and Recommended; there could be many rows before Recommended. I need this code - d[row[4]].update({row[2]: row[3]}) to be dynamic. Data is vertical, one customer data below the other.

Comment: @Shital, this solution works with any number of rows. Checking the code, you will notice there is no reference to 3 rows, or every 3rd row, etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! This has been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding this correctly, that you want a new DataFrame with

```
columns = ['Response Comments', 'Customer name', ...]
```

to reshape your data from the parsed excel file?

Create an empty DataFrame from the known, mandatory column names, e.g

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Response Comments', 'Customer name', ...])
index = 0
```

iterate over the parsed excel file row by row and assign your values

```
for k, row in df.iterrows():
    index += 1

    if row['Column Name'] in df_new:
        df_new.at[index, row['Column Name']] = row['Column Values']

        if row['Column Name'] == 'Recommended':
            continue
```

Not a beauty, but I'm not quite sure what exactly you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: Thanks Marcus for your comment. There is horizontal data block, One customer data listed below the other. One block starts with 1) two rows Response comments, customer name, .... many rows in between... and ends with 2) Recommended. I want to populate 'Key' column with 'customer name' starting with Response comments to Recommended. In above example Value of column 'Key' from rows 1-13 should be brian. Then Row number 14 'Key' column should have next customer's name till the 'Recommended'. I hope I am clear with the requirement.